# Buttons added with Greasemonkey+jQuery appear but don't work on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, greasemonkey

Using Greasemonkey (v.1.8) and jQuery(2.0) and Firefox(20.0) I want to add buttons to each musical piece on pages such as [Through the Night](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01s452q).
I have tried several ways to add the buttons. They appear, but clicking them has no effect. This code leaves out some functions to keep it focused on the problem.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name                BBC Radio 3 Through the Night
// @namespace           Zahphod.beeblebrox
// @description         BBC Radio 3 Through the Night
// @include             http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/*
// @require             http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js
// @require             https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant               GM_log
// @version             0.0.01
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){

var artist;

// wait to "show more"
waitForKeyElements ("#synopsis div.copy a.show-more-truncate", clickShowMoreLink, true);

function clickShowMoreLink (jNode) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

// skip if not a Through the Night playlist
   if ((!document.title) || (document.title.indexOf("Through the Night") < 0)) return;

$("div.full_synopsis>div>p:gt(0)").each(function() {
    artist = $(this).get(0).childNodes[2].textContent.replace(/^\n/, "");

//  var new_button = $("<button>Query " + artist + "</button>");
    var new_button = XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap($("<button>Query " + artist + "</button>"));

    $(this).append(new_button);
    $(new_button).click(function(){ alert(artist);});       

});

})();
```

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a good way to activate a lot of buttons that you add. And, [that particular site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01s452q) is thwarting that code in a couple of not-common ways.

There are several issues with:

```
$(new_button).click(function(){ alert(artist);});
```

1. `new_button` is already a jQuery object.  You would use `new_button.click(...` except for the other problems.
2. Trying to add an event handler to a created node, in this manner, is also vulnerable to scope/sandbox errors -- as appear to have happened in this case.
3. `artist` will not be what you think it is.  You would need a closure at the very least.
4. [This particular site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01s452q) overwrites `alert()`!  So you'd never see the message no matter what.  Debugging with `alert()` is a sucky practice anyway.  Learn to love *Firebug*'s console and use the `console.` family of logging functions.
5. Don't create a bazillion different `click` (or whatever) handlers, one for each button!  This clogs memory, bogs things down, and makes debugging harder.

   jQuery's `.on()` is perfect for this.

Additional issues with that code:

1. `(function(){ ... ... })();` constructs are not needed in Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/Scriptish.
2. `$(this).get(0)`, inside an `.each()` loop, boils down to just `this`.
3. It's smart to always give nodes, that you add, their own class and/or ID.  This helps with manipulation and the inevitable styling. (Use CSS rules for styling, via `GM_addStyle()`.)
4. That page apparently rewrites the HTML where you are adding the buttons.  This trashes poorly added event handlers.  One more reason to use `.on()`.

Putting it all together, change that last section of code to:

```
$("div.full_synopsis>div>p:gt(0)").each ( function () {
    var artist = this.childNodes[2].textContent.replace(/^\n/, "");

    $(this).append (
        '<button class="gmArtistQryBtn" data-artist="' + artist
        + '">Query ' + artist + '</button>'
    );
} );

$("div.full_synopsis").on (
    "click",
    "button.gmArtistQryBtn",
    function (zEvent) {
        var artist = $(zEvent.target).data ("artist") || "OOPSIE!";
        console.log ("artist: ", artist);
    }
);
```

Note how we pass the artist data.  This method survives shallow HTML clones -- which the page may be doing.

Comment: Brock,
That works very nicely.
Wow do I have a lot to learn. Thanks for your knowledge, patience and clear explanations.
I removed the closure I had to make the code simpler, but your method is even better than the code you didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

buttons are wrapped by XPCNativeWrapper under Greasemonkey.

Try XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap as it described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XPCNativeWrapper

Comment: Thanks. I don't write enough Greasemonkey code to remember the pitfalls. The change I made is now in the original question. Still fails for me.